# OpenResty + JWT token

Tags: nginx, jwt, openresty

I set up openresty with LUA this way:

```
export JWT_SECRET="7iN_whateverpsfmjkldfsklmjmlkjsdflmkjsdfmklj"
export JWT_SECRET_IS_BASE64_ENCODED=false
```

Launch openresty manually:

```
/usr/local/openresty/nginx/sbin/nginx
```

Then I create a http request in Postman with the correct JWT (validaded on JWT.io) and this gives me the following error:

```
2020/01/25 12:55:02 [warn] 423#423: *3 [lua] nginx-jwt.lua:49: auth(): Invalid token: invalid payload:
```

Is this a base64 encoding issue?

The JWT issuer is Auth0, so I am sure the JWT secret is not base64 encoded

Comment: You shall provide your OpenResty config/ Lua code/example HTTP request/nginx logs with (reffered) DEBUG level. Otherwise, we may only guess.

Answer (score 0):

Was a wrong hmac file in the openresty release